# How to listview row in textview change text in android?

Tags: android, listview, view

i develop listview in custom row created.but i used list button click open the alert dialog box and selected radio button then dialog is dismiss and i call update function but how to change row text .my code is below.please give me solution.and saved state all row.

```
public class AlMessagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DtoAllMessages> {

        private LayoutInflater inflator;
        private ArrayList<DtoAllMessages> userlist;

        public AlMessagesAdapter(Activity context,
                ArrayList<DtoAllMessages> list) {
            super(context, R.layout.custom_list, list);

            this.userlist = list;
            inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                holder.date_cr = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
                holder.tokenBtn = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tokenBtn);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.tvName, holder.title);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.tvDate, holder.date_cr);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.ivIcon, holder.img);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.tokenBtn, holder.tokenBtn);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

             token = userlist.get(position).getToken();


            token = token.substring(0, token.length() - 3);

            holder.title.setText(userlist.get(position).getName() + "(" + token
                    + ")");

            String type_data = userlist.get(position).getType().toString();

            if ((type_data.equals("text")) || (type_data.equals("photo"))) {
                holder.date_cr.setText(userlist.get(position).getType()
                        + ":Received "
                        + userlist.get(position).getCreated_date());
                holder.tokenBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
            } else if (type_data.equals("out")) {
                holder.date_cr.setText(userlist.get(position).getType()
                        + ":Sent " + userlist.get(position).getCreated_date());
                holder.tokenBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (type_data.equals("text")) {
                holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chatmessage);

            } else if (type_data.equals("photo")) {
                holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.photomessage);

            } else if (type_data.equals("out")) {

                holder.img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outmessafe);
            }

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whitebackground);
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greybackground);
            }

            holder.tokenBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AlertBoxShow(position);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            protected ImageView img;
            protected TextView date_cr;
            protected TextView title;
            protected TextView tokenBtn;
        }
    }
```

and holder.tokenButton click then open the alertdialog box incode below::

```
public void AlertBoxShow(int position) {
        final int pos=position;
        Log.v("log_tag"," position ::"+pos);
        final CharSequence[] items = { " 5 ", " 10 ", " 15 "};

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,  int which) {

                        switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            updateStatus(pos,5);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            // Your code when first option seletced
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            updateStatus(pos,10);
                            // Your code when 2nd option seletced
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            updateStatus(pos,15);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            // Your code when 3rd option seletced
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

and call updatestatus function in i want to holder.title setText and then refresh list row how to possible.and my update status function in below.

```
private void updateStatus(int index, int radioSelectValue) {

        holder.title.setText(userlist.get(index).getName() + "(" + token
                + ")");


    }
```

Comment: Have you ever try to check if the position of your list is correct?.. try to scroll down.. and check the position again... It might be also the reason because of the reuse in the listview

Comment: ya correct poaition get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` to get the position of row item clicked,

Below is to `setTag()`

```
convertView.setTag(R.id.tokenBtn, postion);
```

And then `getTag()` inside `holder.tokenBtn` `onClick()`

```
int pos = (Integer)v.getTag(R.id.tokenBtn);
TextView txtview = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.tvName); // use this TextView 
                                                            to update the value.
AlertBoxShow(pos);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but updateStatus funtion how to set holder.title.

Comment: int pos = (Integer)v.getTag(R.id.tokenBtn); i used this line in onclick event in then crash app and error get null pointer exception.

Comment: did you remove `convertView.setTag(R.id.tokenBtn, holder.tokenBtn);` first?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, i think you are trying to update list item's data according to the selection made by the user in alert box. if so, then change the underlying data in adapter. Do not try to update your textview outside of the adapter. just try to update the data and then call notifyDataSetChanged() method on an adapter. thats it.